# What is the structure of import function in Python?

Tags: import, spyder, vpython

I am searching to do a little programm with 3D animations for one homework for my school.
I work in Spyder space from Anaconda(Python) .

I want to import for that the module vpython installed by pip.
The first line of the function " from visual import * " doesn't work whereas in all examples found on the web, all the programms begins by this line for calling the whole function of this module. Also, i have seen different path and files "vpython" installes on my PC in the path Anaconda3.

So, for me, python don't arrive to find the good path with "import".

Have I to uninstall and install again Python and Anaconda or this is just a problem of grammary from me on my programm and i must help the function import to find the good path, writing some new instructions?

Thanks to have read and i wish you have one idea of what is wrong in this because for the moment I'm blocked.

Comment: IIUC you have two versions of python, remove the current pythonpath and a new one pointing it to anaconda's.

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter/iPython/Anaconda, the import should be

```
from vpython import *
```

In classic VPython, it's

```
from visual import *
```